# New Fragment being created the wrong size

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, size, fragment

I have an app which transitions from fragment to fragment as the user taps on tabs. One of these fragments has a webview in it.
The issue I am having is that if the user has the soft keyboard visible and then navigates to the webview fragment, the webview is created in the wrong size. The webView gets created in a size as if the keyboard was still up.

I have tried to extend the webView class used by the fragment and try and set the correct size in OnMeasure. This does not help.

It seems like there is something about a webView that does not make it re-size correctly.

Another hacky option might be to write a javascript interface class and have the javascript trigger a resize?

What I am looking for is a way to create the fragment and the webView in the correct size but there is no easy way to know what the "correct" size should be. 
Any ideas on how I can fix this?